# Adding completion to observable that never complete

Tags: cordova, rxjs, cordova-plugins

I am trying to add a completion to cordova plugin with ionic wrapper. So i will catch the completion in a subscriber. So i got someSerive that is a ionic wrapper to the cordova plaugin:

```js
 startListen(){
            return this.someService.startListen().pipe(
                switchMap((response) => {
                    return new Observable(subscriber => {
                        if (response.index !== undefined) {
                            subscriber.next(1);
                        }
                        if (response.errorTitle === Message.NOT_FOUND) {
                            subscriber.error(Message.NOT_FOUND);
                        }
                        if (response.errorTitle === Message.CANCELLED) {
                            console.log('blah blah'); <---### IS PRINTED
                            subscriber.complete();
                        }
                    });
                }),
            );
        }
```

And i call it in some component:

```js
 startListen(){
            this.someFacade.startListen().subscribe(
                (x) => console.log('next', x),
                (x) => console.log('error', x),
                () => console.log('complete'), <---# NOT PRINNTED
            );
```

The problem that the console.log('complete') is never trigered.

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`takeWhile` operator does what you want:

```
this.someService.startListen().pipe(
  takeWhile(response => response.errorTitle !== Message.CANCELLED),
  switchMap(response => response.index !== undefined
    ? of(response.index)
    : throwError(response.errorTitle)
  )
```

Comment: Thanks. Much better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I need to close the first observable too. So my solution:

```js
const completed = new Subject();
        return this.someService.startListen().pipe(
            switchMap((response) => {
                return new Observable(subscriber => {
                    if (response.index !== undefined) {
                        subscriber.next(response.index);
                    }
                    if (response.errorTitle === Message.NOT_FOUND) {
                        subscriber.next(Message.NOT_FOUND);
                    }
                    if (response.errorTitle === Message.CANCELLED) {
                        subscriber.complete();
                        completed.next();
                        completed.unsubscribe();
                    }
                });
            }),
            takeUntil(completed)
        );
```